# Converting from json to a class with gson does not appear to do anything

Tags: java, gson, json

I am attempting to deserialize a json string using [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). Here is my code

```
static class ReturnPramaters {
    public ReturnPramaters()
    {
    }
    public Boolean LoginFailed = true;
    public String LoginFailedReason = "";
    public String AppPath  = "";
    public String WorkstiaonGuid = "";
    public String RDPUsername  = "";
    public String RDPPassword  = "";
    public int StartMode = -1;
    public String ServerAddress  = "";
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = sendGetRequest("http://example.com:80/Rdp/json/login","username=test&password=1234");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ReturnPramaters para = gson.fromJson(json, ReturnPramaters.class);
    if(para.LoginFailed)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, para.LoginFailedReason, "Login Failed",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    else {
        //...
    }
}
```

here is my json string that is retured from the get request.

```
"{"d":{"__type":"ReturnPramaters:#ServerApp","AppPath":"C:\\Remote Desktop Manager\\Launcher\\Launcher.exe","LoginFailed":false,"LoginFailedReason":null,"RDPPassword":"XjE2QAL","RDPUsername":"test09","ServerAddress":"example.com","StartMode":1,"WorkstiaonGuid":"96175701-f72a-44e9-8ee1-6eb756293654"}}"
```

However after `ReturnPramaters para = gson.fromJson(json, ReturnPramaters.class);` para still has all of it's uninitialized values. What is going wrong that is causing this to fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try truncating the incoming string before passing to GSON, so that it looks like this

```
"{
    "AppPath":"C:\\Remote Desktop Manager\\Launcher\\Launcher.exe",
    "LoginFailed":false,
    "LoginFailedReason":null,
    "RDPPassword":"XjE2QAL",
    "RDPUsername":"test09",
    "ServerAddress":"example.com",
    "StartMode":1,
    "WorkstiaonGuid":"96175701-f72a-44e9-8ee1-6eb756293654"
}"
```

The object that you currently have in JSON represents the following Java object

```
public class MyClass{
  ReturnPramaters d;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that JSON you are mapping to is wrapped in another object with `d` and `_type` fields.

So create a simple wrapper Class:

```
class JsonWrapper{
    public ReturnPramaters d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type class is static. Is that going to work?

Comment: Yes, it says in the documentation that static type classes are fine (in fact required if your class is a nested class (which it actually is, i just posted a simplified case))